# SQLCLR Stored procedure datatypes

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr, sqldatatypes

I decided to create a SQLCLR stored procedure to replace a SQL Server stored procedure due to it's complexity.

**Question:** is there any data type or API restrictions when we write CLR stored procedures? If so, can someone give me any heads up on this.

I am planning to use `var, List<T>, DataTable, DataRow[]` and a `Queue` along with few `LINQ` extension methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a fairly open-ended question as there are nuances in both what can be done in the .NET / CLR code itself and what datatypes can/should be used as input/output parameters.

Starting with the basics, the nuances depend on what version of SQL Server you are using, and which particular question is being asked.

## .NET Framework Versions

- **Mixed-mode is not allowed:** only a single CLR version can be used within the SQL Server CLR Host, and the CLR version depends on the version of SQL Server and cannot be changed
- **SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2:** Statically bound to CLR 2.0
- **SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016:** Statically bound to CLR 4.0

## .NET Framework Libraries and Data Type Mappings

### SQL Server 2005

**[Supported .NET Framework Libraries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279(v=sql.90).aspx):**

- CustomMarshalers
- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.VisualC
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Configuration
- System.Data
- System.Data.OracleClient
- System.Data.SqlXml
- System.Deployment
- System.Security
- System.Transactions
- System.Web.Services
- System.Xml

**Data Types:**

- Specifics: [SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(v=sql.90).aspx)
- Main page with more info (i.e. handling NULLs, etc): [SQL Server Data Types in the .NET Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131049(v=sql.90).aspx)

### SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, and 2016:

**[Supported .NET Framework Libraries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx):** (*2 libraries added as noted below*)

- CustomMarshalers
- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.VisualC
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Configuration
- System.Data
- System.Data.OracleClient
- System.Data.SqlXml
- System.Deployment
- System.Security
- System.Transactions
- System.Web.Services
- System.Xml
- System.Core.dll (*added in SQL Server 2008*)
- System.Xml.Linq.dll (*added in SQL Server 2008*)

**Data Types:**

- Specifics: [SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)
- Main page with more info (i.e. handling NULLs, etc): [SQL Server Data Types in the .NET Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131049.aspx)

## Misc.

- Regarding Data Types: if there is a `Sql*` type available (e.g. `SqlInt32`) then use it; don't use the .NET type in the C# method for input parameters (e.g. `int` or `Int32`). Only use the native .NET type if there is no `Sql*` type for the SQL Server Data Type to map to. The two common instances of this exception are using `object` (which can be `DbNull.Value`) to map to `SQL_VARIANT`, and `DateTime` / `DateTime?` which map to `DATETIME2`.
- You can reference / use 3rd party assemblies as well as Framework Libraries outside of those listed above, but you then need to import them with a `PERMISSION_SET` of `UNSAFE` into the database in which your code also resides. You will also probably need to set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` in order to set them to `UNSAFE` because it does not seem possible (not that I can find, anyway) to create the Asymmetric Key from Microsoft provided DLLs.
- Generally speaking, anything written against .NET 2.0 such that it works in SQL Server 2005 should work in any of the later versions of SQL Server. I have yet to come across something that works in .NET 2.0 on 2005 that doesn't work in any of the version to come after 2005.
- You cannot pass Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs) into a SQLCLR-based object (Stored Procedure, Function, etc.). That point, as well as some other helpful info, is noted in the MSDN documentation for [CLR Stored Procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx)
- I have not seen any issues when using `List<T>`, `DataTable`, and `DataRow[]`.
- I have not used `Queue` or `var` but would not expect any issues when using them.
- It has been years since I tried `LINQ` but seem to recall the only issue being that it was not included in the SQL Server 2005 set of supported Framework Libraries so that didn't work for me as I need to support 2005 - 2014, but for anyone who doesn't need to worry about SQL Server 2005 it *should* be ok.
- For more details on the topic of SQLCLR, I have a series of articles on SQL Server Central (free registration required): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)